# app.yaml cannot locate entry point after changing main.py into __init__.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I followed this [Large Flask Applications](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/packages/) tutorial and changed my `main.py` into `__init__.py`. Now, running the app locally uses `flask run` instead of `python main.py`.

The problem: when I deploy the app, I get a *502 Bad Gateway* error obviously. I know that, by default, App Engine will look for the main.py file as an entry point.

But now that the entry point has changed, what can I do?

Can Google App Engine work with large Flask apps?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation [The Python Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime), you can change the `entrypoint` value in the `app.yaml` file, so it would redirect your `__init__.py` file.

Besides that, I would recommend you to take a look at the following links, where there is more information, regarding building and developing an application with Python and Flask.

- [Building a Python 3.7 App on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app)
- [Python App Engine 2017: Building a simple Flask app](https://medium.com/the-infinite-machine/python-app-engine-2017-building-a-simple-flask-app-b55f60755204)

These links should provide a good overview of development with these two applications, which should cover how to avoid such errors that you are facing.

Let me know if the information helped you!